# ImportError: No module named blahblah, but it's in the working directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, python-import

I'm *not* a Python programmer, so I assume this is a rookie question.

I'm importing a cython file into a script in python (the file extension of the cython file is pyx if that makes a difference). I do so using this;

```
from im2col_cython import col2im_cython, im2col_cython
```

Here is the error I get;

```
from im2col_cython import col2im_cython, im2col_cython

ImportError: No module named im2col_cython
```

The file is in the same folder as the script that it is imported in, I have also set the working directory to that folder (just incase there was some issue with that). I'm using Anaconda, Python 2.7, Windows 7.

I've been trying to fix this for around 4 hours, it seems like a simple error but this is my first real foray into Python.

Comment: Is the name of the folder you have your scripts in `im2col_cython`? If that's the case, try adding an empty file named `__init__.py` in that same folder

Comment: Use THIS and post it here (along with the full path of the lib)
print( "Executable running THIS script: { " + sys.executable+ " }" )
print( "Full path file name of THIS script: { " + os.path.realpath(__file__) " }" )
print( "Full path directory to THIS script: { " + os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+ " }" )
print( "Current working directory         : { " + os.getcwd()+ " }" )
print( "Has THIS file started Python?     : { " + { True: "Yes", False: "No" }[(__name__ == "__main__")]  + " }" )
print( "Which Python version is running?  : { " + sys.version.replace("\n", "") + " }" )

Comment: @IronFist the folder name isn't the same as the script name. I do have a _init_.py in the folder nonetheless.

Comment: @Claudio I don't know what you're comment means. It looks like a script to run, but i don't know what to do with it! Sorry

Comment: Put it along with import sys, os, platform, psutil at the top of the script which can't import and see what happens when it runs - maybe you find this way the solution to your problem. You can see then clearly the current directory and some other details worth to know attempting to find out what the problem is. At least you provide not enough details in your question to make for others possible to tell you directly what the problem is.

Comment: @Claudio thanks, I understand now. When I run that at the top of the file it just prints it all out as text (the output starts: print( "Executable running THIS script: { " + sys.executable+ " }" ) print( "Full ...) What am I doing wrong to actually get the information like sys.executable (rather than printing the text)?

Comment: Sometimes is it so that what you think is, is not as you think, so let the script tell you its path and the executable running it to be sure that what you assume is right. Post the output along with the paths of the lib you want to import - this should be enough to see what the problem is.

Comment: @Claudio I don't think it's working as expected. The output is as follows;    print( "Executable running THIS script: { " + sys.executable+ " }" ) print( "Full path file name of THIS script: { " + os.path.realpath(file) " }" ) print( "Full path directory to THIS script: { " + os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(file))+ " }" ) print( "Current working directory : { " + os.getcwd()+ " }" ) print( "Has THIS file started Python? : { " + { True: "Yes", False: "No" }[(name == "main")] + " }" ) print( "Which Python version is running? : { " + sys.version.replace("\n", "") + " }" )

Comment: Underneath that it says: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140136/discussion-between-claudio-and-fraserofsmeg).